# How to increase badge on submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

In my project there are 3 main roles:

`1  - Authorize person`

`2  - Employee`

`3  - Hr`

When the `employee` submit the `replication slip` there should be increase in the badge of `authorize`

here is my code:`for - employee`

`(views/employee/emain)`

```
 <%= form_for (@replication) do |f| %>
  <h2><center><u>Replication slip</u></center></h2>
  <table width = "600">
  <tr>
  <td>
      <%= f.label :SR_NO %>
  </td>
  <td>
      <%= f.number_field :sr_no , :id => "txt_RegionName" %>
  </td>

  <td>
    <%= f.label :Particular %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= f.text_area :particular , :id => "txt_Region" %>
  </td>

  <td>
    <%= f.label :Unit %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= f.text_field :unit ,:id => "txt_Regio" %>
  </td>


  <td> 
    <%= f.label :Required_Quantity %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= f.text_field :quantity ,:id => "txt_Regi" %>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  <td>
  <input type="button"  name="add" id="btn_AddToList" value="add" class="btn btn-primary" />
  <input type="button"  name="Done" id="btn_AddToList1" value="Done" class="btn btn-success" />
  <div id="divMsg" style="display:none;">
  <i class = "fa fa-key"></i>
  </div>
  </td></tr>
  </table>
  <br />
  <center>
  <div id="table-lst-regions"> 
  <table id="lst_Regions" style="width: 500px;" border= "2" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
   <tr>
     <td><b>SR-NO</b></td>
     <td><b>Perticular</b></td>
    <td><b>Unit</b></td>
    <td><b>Quantity Required</b></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
 </center>
   <input type="button" id= "submit" value="Submit Repication"  class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data- target="#myModal" data-loading-text="loding..." />
  <% end %>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><center>REPLICATION SLIP</center></h4>
        FROM: <u><b><%= current_emp.username.upcase %></b></u>
      </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
  </div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

`(employee.js:-)`

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
$('#submit').prop('disabled', true).removeClass("btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary").addClass("btn btn-block btn-lg btn-default");

 $('#btn_AddToList').click(function () {

 $('#submit').prop('disabled', true).removeClass("btn btn-block btn-lg btn-info").addClass("btn btn-block btn-lg btn-default");
var val = $('#txt_RegionName').val();
var val2 = $('#txt_Region').val();
var val3 = $('#txt_Regio').val();
var val4 = $('#txt_Regi').val();
$('#lst_Regions').append('<tr><td>' + val + '</td>' + '<td>' + val2 + '</td>' + '<td>' + val3 + '</td>' + '<td>' + val4 + '</td></tr>');
$('#txt_RegionName').val('').focus();
$('#txt_Region').val('');
    $('#txt_Regio').val('');
    $('#txt_Regi').val('');
$('#btn_AddToList1').click(function () {
     $('#submit').prop('disabled', false).removeClass("btn btn-block btn-lg btn-default").addClass('btn btn-block btn-lg btn-info');
  $('body').on('shown.bs.modal', '#myModal', function () {
  $(".modal-body").html($("#table-lst-regions").html());
   });
  });
});
});
```

`(for authorize:-)`

```
<li>
 <div id="dLabel" role="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#" href="#"><i class="fa fa-money"></i> Replication<span class = "badge">0</span>
  </d>
  li>
```

**`what should i include so that i can increase the count of the badge on ever submission of the replication form?`**

Comment: I would suggest slimming this down if you want to have a chance to get this answered. [This guy](http://sscce.org/) is often sited. A jsbin or jsfiddle would also go a long way.

Answer (score 0):

In the following piece of code:

```
<span class = "badge">0</span>
```

have you considered declaring replacing the zero by a variable. When the replication is submited, you also submit this variable, and you should have in your backend a function that increases a counter and writes it to the front end variable.